# One case of comma usage

Tags: pronunciation, commas

Do I need to put a comma at this (highlighted) position? Why? Why not?

> In a sub-picosecond range`,` this radical is transformed into hydroxyl radical...

My collaborator from USA insists on putting in it.
As for me, no comma should be there, since the sentence becomes divided.
I tried to find a rule for this case, but it was not very convincing, saying that there are two cases with and without comma.

Comment: I would say that the comma isn't strictly necessary but it **does** aid comprehension, and so you should use it.

Comment: You should, that comma belongs there.

Comment: @Taurus, is there a strict rule for such cases? As I said below, being a Russian, I do not fill it, so the rule might help me. For me it is one sentence with one idea, so I do not need any stops while reading. I've put this comma back, since english-speakers are telling me to do so.

Comment: @saldenisov I am not a native English speaker either, but in my opinion, a comma doesn't exactly divide a sentence, that is what a period "." or a semicolon ";" does; a comma is just a very short pause, in actual speech, i would use it to play with the audience's attention (e.g in your sentence i would use it to give some extra focus to the first part:  `in a sub-picosecond range`).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your collaborator is absolutely right. Punctuation is very important, it is like breathing. Of course the sentence is correct also without, but putting a comma helps the reader to breathe and wait for the second part of it. In a technical reading this is maybe less important, because you are concentrated on other things, but in a novel or in a newspaper the wrong use, or the non use of the punctuation is very bad. Let me also say that a "stupid" comma is so important that can change the whole meaning of the sentence, as the famous phrase attributed to the oracles of Dodona:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibis_redibis_nunquam_per_bella_peribis

that you may find also in the form

*"Ibis et redibis non morieris"* in bello.
Depending on the position of the comma, the response changes completely.

Comment: I would not use breathe at this point, I would say all phrase in one breath, because only one idea is expressed. Maybe because I'm Russian, in Russian I will not put it there. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @ealy a comma shouldn't be long enough to allow you to breathe, a semicolon perhaps (though i usually find myself using commas instead).